# NullPointerException Location on Longitude and Latitude

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager

**The problem:** The application is to take in readings of longitude and latitude from the device. The activity which performs this function works well the 1st time... But when one enters into the activity the second time the application crashes, giving the following `NullPointerException`:

```
08-25 19:53:36.517: E/AndroidRuntime(26672): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 19:53:36.517: E/AndroidRuntime(26672): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vaw.selfhelp/com.vaw.selfhelp.SmsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 19:53:36.517: E/AndroidRuntime(26672):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
08-25 19:53:36.517: E/AndroidRuntime(26672):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
08-25 19:53:36.517: E/AndroidRuntime(26672):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-25 19:53:36.517: E/AndroidRuntime(26672):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
08-25 19:53:36.517: E/AndroidRuntime(26672):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-25 19:53:36.517: E/AndroidRuntime(26672):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-25 19:53:36.517: E/AndroidRuntime(26672):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
08-25 19:53:36.517: E/AndroidRuntime(26672):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 19:53:36.517: E/AndroidRuntime(26672):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-25 19:53:36.517: E/AndroidRuntime(26672):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
08-25 19:53:36.517: E/AndroidRuntime(26672):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
08-25 19:53:36.517: E/AndroidRuntime(26672):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-25 19:53:36.517: E/AndroidRuntime(26672): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 19:53:36.517: E/AndroidRuntime(26672):    at com.vaw.selfhelp.SmsActivity.onCreate(SmsActivity.java:85)
08-25 19:53:36.517: E/AndroidRuntime(26672):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-25 19:53:36.517: E/AndroidRuntime(26672):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
08-25 19:53:36.517: E/AndroidRuntime(26672):    ... 11 more
```

**The code:**

```
lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                    Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };

        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);

        longitude = location.getLongitude(); //this is line 85 which the logcat is referring to
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
```

Can somebody please help !

Comment: what happens on line 85 of `SMSActivity`

Comment: i commented that out ... longitude = location.getLongitude();

Answer (score 0):

The code is probably working since you said it only crashes on the second return to the activity. You should probably reassign location object during activity onResume() callback.

Comment: i actually tested it on another device higher than android 2.3.3, it crashed instantly.

Comment: re-assign as in ?? when the user goes out of the activity the activity calls a finish() function.

Comment: You mentioned that it crashes when the user enters the activity a second time. I assumed that you launch a second activity that makes this activity goes into onPaused() and then onResume() state. Try running location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); in onResume()?

Comment: i think that should work ... its like the activity needs the GPS to be turned on at all times. If the GPS is on the application wont crash.